# Case Count 0 Digit in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Why Don't work Case 0 in my code? In this example, if there is nothing in that line (nothing), it should be +1, but it shows me the result 0.

```
 Dim StartIndex = TextBoz1.Lines.Length - 1
    For i = StartIndex To 0 Step -1
        Dim lineVals As String() = TextBoz1.Lines(i).Split(",")
        Select Case lineVals.Count()
            Case 0
                lastDraw1 += 1
                lastDraw2 += 1
                lastDraw3 += 1
            Case 1
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 += 1
                lastDraw3 += 1
            Case 2
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 = 0
                lastDraw3 += 1
            Case 3
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 = 0
                lastDraw3 = 0
        End Select
    Next
    TextBox8.Text = lastDraw1
    TextBox9.Text = lastDraw2
    TextBox10.Text = lastDraw3
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim lineVals As String() = TextBoz1.Lines(i).Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. Set `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not equal to zero. Try a small sample.

```
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim v As String() = s.Split(","c)

    Console.WriteLine(v.Count) ' Display 1
```

In your case, you would need to check if the string is empty first.

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoz1.Lines(i)) Then
        lastDraw1 += 1
        lastDraw2 += 1
        lastDraw3 += 1
    Else
        Dim lineVals As String() = TextBoz1.Lines(i).Split(",")
        Select Case lineVals.Count()
            Case 1
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 += 1
                lastDraw3 += 1
            Case 2
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 = 0
                lastDraw3 += 1
            Case 3
                lastDraw1 = 0
                lastDraw2 = 0
                lastDraw3 = 0
        End Select
    End If
```

Comment: @AndreiMirel if it has helped resolve your issue, please upvote and or accept the answer as a way to say thanks. This also helps others that may come across this answer was a solution to the issue.